# Impact of memory leak on other process

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a query related to memory leak.

A 32 bit Linux based system is running multiple active processes A,B,C,D. All the processes are allocating/deallocating memory from the heap. Now if process A is contionusly leaking a significant amount of memory, could it happen that after a  certain amount of time process B cant find any memory to allocate from the heap?

As per my understanding, each process is provided with a unque VM of 2GB from the OS. But there is a mappig between the VM and the physical memory.

Comment: ok. But, which is the question?

Comment: The question is whether malloc can fail in process B, C, D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel does memory overcommit by default.
When a process request a memory segment with malloc() the memory is not automatically allocated.
You may have 4 processes malloc()ing 2gb each and not having any problem.
The problem arise when the process make use (initialize, bzero, copy) of the malloc()ed memory.
You may even malloc more memory than the system may reserve for you, without any problem, and malloc() doesn't even return NULL!!

Comment: dAm2k, I am seeing malloc failures in B leading to program crash which doesnt have any memory leaks. And obviously the processses allocating memory are using it for storing data and for that memset, memcopy, and other string operations are used.

Comment: try the dmesg command and check that the OOM killer is not killing your process B

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the total amount of VM (RAM + swap space) is exhausted by process A, then `malloc` in any of the other processes might fail because of that. Linux hides processes' memory spaces from other processes, but it doesn't magically create extra memory in your machine. (Although it may seem to do so due to its [overcommit](http://opsmonkey.blogspot.nl/2007/01/linux-memory-overcommit.html) behavior.)

In addition, Linux may employ its OOM killer when memory is running low.

Comment: Thanks, larsmans, for your answer. Actually in our test-bed we are observing this scenario.

Comment: Just to add that in case of high memory pressure, linux may fire the infamous OOM (Out Of Memory) killer and kill other processes.

Comment: dAm2k, can you please elaborate on this. We have a call-server running on the Linux system. There are other collaborating processes assisting the server. Now when we put the sever under load test, it crashes with malloc failure after running 5000 calls each having duration of 20 mins.

Comment: @Bidyut if you run the "dmesg" command and you can see kernel messages with something related to the OOM killer (Out of Memory: Killed process ...) then the system is killing your processes to free memory.